# execution of loop stops after recursive function call - javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that makes an array of all the possible permutations without repetition of the chars in a given array. The problem is that when the recursive call of recur() is made, the rest of the for loop is not executed and as a result the var total consists of 1 string.

```
   function recur(arr,wordArr) {
    if(arr.length == 0) {
      total.push(wordArr);
    } else {
        for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
          var temp = arr;
          var newwordArr = wordArr;
          newwordArr += temp.splice(i, 1);
          recur(temp,newwordArr);
        }
    }
  }



  var arr = "abc".split("");
  var total = [];
  recur(arr,'');
  console.log(total);
```

Calling recur([a,b],'') should make total = ['ab','ba']

There is something I'm not seeing or what I'm trying to do is simply not allowed. Couldn't find the answer to this even tought I did a lot of searching.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it wasn't sufficient for what you need, but [here is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927452/recursively-print-all-permutations-of-a-string-javascript) that does what you're trying to do. Check it out and see if you can replicate the results/adapt your code.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy your array in each step of for loop

```
function recur(arr,wordArr) {
if(arr.length == 0) {
  total.push(wordArr);
} else {
    for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
      var temp = Array.from(arr);
      var newwordArr = wordArr;
      newwordArr += temp.splice(i, 1);
      recur(temp,newwordArr);
    }
}
}
```

Because in JS, all objects are referances, and writing `var temp = arr;` it will not create new array, it just will create reference to old array `arr`.

```
Array.from(oldArray|oldSet)
```

this function will create new Array and fill with old.

Read more about

- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: I was hoping for it to be this kind of problem. Thanks a lot!!