# Project Euler #43: Why does my answer take so long?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on [Problem 43](https://projecteuler.net/problem=43)

I have done a brute force solution. But it should execute in O(n) time.

On my computer it takes a few hours to complete. Is there anything I can do to speed up the computational complexity?

```
const main = () => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 1023456789; i < 9876543211; i++) {
    // for (let i = 1406357289; i < 1406357290; i++) {
        if (isPandigital(i)) {
            var d = i.toString().split("");
            if (checkSubString (d[1], d[2], d[3], 2) &&
                checkSubString (d[2], d[3], d[4], 3) &&
                checkSubString (d[3], d[4], d[5], 5) &&
                checkSubString (d[4], d[5], d[6], 7) &&
                checkSubString (d[5], d[6], d[7], 11) &&
                checkSubString (d[6], d[7], d[8], 13) &&
                checkSubString (d[7], d[8], d[9], 17)) {
                total += i;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
};

const checkSubString = (d1, d2, d3, prime) => parseInt(`${d1}${d2}${d3}`) % prime === 0;

const isPandigital = num => {
    var allNums = num.toString().split("").map(item => parseInt(item, 10)).sort();
    for (var k = 0; k < allNums.length; k++) {
        if (allNums[k] !== k) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(main()); // 16695334890
```

Comment: Is the final answer `16695334890` correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: How about creating a table of powers of 10, then extracting triples of digits by using the modulo operator with appropriately chosen powers of 10? EDIT: Sort of similarly, in isPandigital, you can loop over the digits by using the modulo and divison operators (mind to floor after the division); I'd suggest storing which digits you've already found in an array, returning false when there is a duplicate digit (if there isn't, and it's of the right length, it's pandigital).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than iterating over *all* numbers inside the range, how about instead generating only the permutations which result in pandigital numbers, and then iterating over *them* instead? That'll cut down on a *lot* of the calculations:

Tweaking the permuting function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39928045) answer:

```js
const checkSubString = (d1, d2, d3, prime) => `${d1}${d2}${d3}` % prime === 0;
const main = () => {
  let total = 0;
  const pandigitalNumbers = permut('1234567890').filter(char => char[0] !== '0');
  for (const i of pandigitalNumbers) {
    var d = [...String(i)];
    if (checkSubString(d[1], d[2], d[3], 2) &&
      checkSubString(d[2], d[3], d[4], 3) &&
      checkSubString(d[3], d[4], d[5], 5) &&
      checkSubString(d[4], d[5], d[6], 7) &&
      checkSubString(d[5], d[6], d[7], 11) &&
      checkSubString(d[6], d[7], d[8], 13) &&
      checkSubString(d[7], d[8], d[9], 17)) {
      total += Number(i);
    }
  }
  return total;
};
console.log(main());


function permut(string) {
  const arr = [];
  if (string.length < 2) return string;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    const char = string[i];
    if (!string.includes(char)) continue;
    const remainingString = string.slice(0, i) + string.slice(i + 1, string.length);
    for (var subPermutation of permut(remainingString))
      arr.push(char + subPermutation)
  }
  return arr;
}
```

The snippet above runs in about 4 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Ooohh yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I didn't even think of that. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Two tweaks: d4 has to be even and d6 can only be 0 or 5.  That means you can terminate some selections early.