# Algorithm to form two teams from a list of 10 people based on skillindex

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, math

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that checks all possible combinations in a list of players and makes two teams of 5 with the closest possible difference in total `skillIndex`. So far I have come up with the following exhausting permutation:

I am wondering if there is a better way to come up with a result which would suggest the 5 best team combinations based on the `skillIndex`. Do you guys have any idea what is an efficient way of solving this?

My end goal is to have two teams where one player can only be in one team. And the teams have a skillindex which is as close to each other as they can be.

My approach for now has been to find all possible combinations of the array, split this array in half so I have two teams. Then calculate the skillindex of both arrays and compare the difference between them. If the difference is <= 5 then print the generated team.

So one hard requirement is that with the same number of players teams consist of different players therefore I need multiple options.

```
const permutate = () => {
    const presentPlayers = [
        { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
        { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
        { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
        { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 },
        { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
        { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
        { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
        { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
        { name: 'i', skillIndex: 50 },
        { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
    ];

    const getDifference = (a, b) => {
        return Math.abs(a - b);
    };

    function permutation(array) {
        function p(array, temp) {
            let i;
            let x;
            if (!array.length) {
                let team1Index = 0;
                let team2Index = 0;
                const half = temp.length / 2;
                const team1 = temp.splice(0, half);
                const team2 = temp.splice(-half);
                team1.forEach((player) => {
                    team1Index += parseFloat(player.skillIndex, 10);
                });
                team2.forEach((player) => {
                    team2Index += parseFloat(player.skillIndex, 10);
                });
                const difference = getDifference(team1Index, team2Index);
                if (difference === 5) {
                    console.log({ team1, team2 });
                    debugger;
                }
                result.push(temp);
            }
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                x = array.splice(i, 1)[0];
                p(array, temp.concat(x));
                array.splice(i, 0, x);
            }
        }

        const result = [];
        p(array, []);
        return result;
    }

    console.log(permutation(presentPlayers));
};
```

So for now I came up with this solution based mainly on the tips of you guys. I run this code 252 times:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < presentPlayers.length; i++) {
                const player = presentPlayers[i];
                players.push(player);
            }
            for (let i = players.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
                const temp = players[i];
                players[i] = players[j];
                players[j] = temp;
            }
            let team1Index = 0;
            let team2Index = 0;
            const half = players.length / 2;
            const team1 = players.splice(0, half);
            const team2 = players.splice(-half);
            team1.forEach((player) => {
                team1Index += parseFloat(player.skillIndex, 10);
            });
            team2.forEach((player) => {
                team2Index += parseFloat(player.skillIndex, 10);
            });
            const difference = getDifference(team1Index, team2Index);
            const sortedTeam1 = team1.sort((a, b) => {
                return b.skillIndex - a.skillIndex;
            });
            const sortedTeam2 = team2.sort((a, b) => {
                return b.skillIndex - a.skillIndex;
            });
            if (difference < 10) {
                proposedTeams.push({
                    sortedTeam1,
                    sortedTeam2,
                    difference,
                    team1Index,
                    team2Index,
                    goalSkill,
                });
            }
```

Comment: Consider this post on permuations of strings. Its very similar to what you are looking for but in a more generalized way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927452/recursively-print-all-permutations-of-a-string-javascript

Comment: @MarcoMancarne What is your end goal? In your post you talk about finding 2 teams, each team being made of 5 players, which are the closest in skill index (I imagine a player can't be on more than one team), and then at another point, about finding 5 best team combinations. Is your function supposed to do both or do you need two different functions?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have just updated my questions. My end goal is to list the top 5 suggestions of two teams which skillindex is as close to each other as they can be. A player can only be in one team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach.  It does not try to be particularly efficient, because choosing five teams out of ten is a small problem.  (10 choose 5 is only 252, and that already double-counts the splits into teams.)  We can do this quickly enough not to matter for many practical purposes.

We should note that the data has 11 different splits into teams only five points apart, so  you might want to test with data more varied, if that's realistic.

Here is an implementation:

```js
// utility functions
const sum = (ns) => ns.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const combinations = (xs, n) => 
  xs .flatMap ((x, i) => 
    n == 1
      ? [[x]]
      : combinations (xs .slice (i + 1), n - 1) 
          .map (combo => [x, ...combo])
  )

const complement = (xs, ys) => xs .filter (x => !ys .includes (x))

const splits = (fn, xs) => 
  combinations (xs, Math.ceil(xs.length / 2))
    .map (c => [c, complement (xs, c)])
    .reduce (
      ({all, uniq}, [a, b], _, __, ka = fn(a), kb = fn(b)) =>
        uniq.has(ka) || uniq.has(kb) 
          ? {all, uniq} 
          : {all: all.concat([[a, b]]), uniq: uniq.add(ka).add(kb)},
      {all: [], uniq: new Set()}
    ).all


// helper function
const skillTotal = (players) =>
  sum (players .map (p => p. skillIndex))


// main function
const nClosestSplits = (n, players) => 
  splits (xs => xs.map(x => x.name).join('~'), players) .map (([a, b]) => ({
    teamA: a,
    teamB: b,
    scoreDiff: Math.abs(skillTotal(a) - skillTotal(b))
  }))
    .sort (({scoreDiff: a}, {scoreDiff: b}) => a - b)
    .slice (0, n)


// sample data
const presentPlayers = [{name: 'a', skillIndex: 100}, {name: 'b', skillIndex: 100}, {name: 'c', skillIndex: 90}, {name: 'd', skillIndex: 25}, {name: 'e', skillIndex: 60}, {name: 'f', skillIndex: 80}, {name: 'g', skillIndex: 70}, {name: 'h', skillIndex: 60}, {name: 'i', skillIndex: 50}, {name: 'j', skillIndex: 50}]


// demo
const display = (splits) =>
  console .log (splits.map(({teamA, teamB, scoreDiff}) => `[${
    teamA .map(a => `${a.name}`).join(', ')}] (total ${skillTotal(teamA)}) vs  [${
    teamB .map(b => `${b.name}`).join(', ')}] (total ${skillTotal(teamB)}),  diff = ${
    scoreDiff
  }`).join('\n'))

display (nClosestSplits (5, presentPlayers))
```

We start with some utility functions, ones that you might use across many parts of one project or across projects.  I would probably place them in a personal utility library:

- **`sum`** simply adds together the numbers in a list
- **`combinations`** finds all subsets of `n` elements from a list of items.  For example:

  ```js
  combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2) //=>
  // [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d"], ["c", "d"]]
  ```
- **`complement`** find all the elements of one array **not** found in another.

  ```js
  complement(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'd']) //=> ['b', 'c', 'e']
  ```
- **`splits`** uses `combinations` and `complements` to find all equal-sized partitions of a list of elements.  It requires a helper function to turn our arrays into a single key to test on.  We can't easily test the elements themselves, since we have to store them in a `Set`, which uses reference equality rather than value equality.  So we might, for instance do this:

  ```js
  splits ((xs) => xs.join('~'), ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) //=>
  // [
  //   [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]], 
  //   [["a", "c"], ["b", "d"]], 
  //   [["a", "d"], ["b", "c"]]
  // ]
  ```

Then we have a single helper function (which I distinguish from utility functions because they are useful only in this problem, helping us factor into meaningful parts and/or reduce repetition in our main code):

- **`skillTotal`** just totals the `skillIndex` property for every player in an array.

We use these to build our main function `nClosestSplits`.  This function takes `n`, the number of top values to choose, and a list of players.  If finds all splits into teams, turns them into useful output objects with two teams and a score differential value, then sorts them by this differential, and chooses the top `n` values.

That `sort`/`slice` combination is less efficient than other methods of finding the top `n` values of an array.  But it is easy to implement and is probably *good enough* if you are only looking at choosing five of ten players and hence have only 126 splits to compare.  If you wanted to split 30 into 15, then you'd have 7.5 million to sort, and we might have to look for a more efficient implementation.  They're not hard to find, but that will take us further afield.

### Update

Following a suggestion in the comments, I added a `shuffle` function to help randomize among the (possibly many) top answers.  Any decent `shuffle` function should do.  I used this:

```js
const shuffle = (_xs) => {
  const xs = [... _xs]
  for (let i = xs .length; i --> 0; ) {
    const j = Math .floor (Math .random () * i)
    xs [i] = [xs [j], xs [j] = xs [i]] [0] // or any swap method
  }
  return xs
}
```

with this change to the main function:

```js
const nClosestSplits = (n, players, swap) => 
  shuffle(
    splits (xs => xs.map(x => x.name).join('~'), players) .map (([a, b]) => ({
      teamA: a,
      teamB: b,
      scoreDiff: Math.abs(skillTotal(a) - skillTotal(b))
    }))
  )
   .sort (({scoreDiff: a}, {scoreDiff: b}) => a - b)
   .slice (0, n)
```

which yields more randomized results such as

```
[a, b, d, g, i] (total 345)  vs  [c, e, f, h, j] (total 340),  diff = 5
[a, c, d, f, i] (total 345)  vs  [b, e, g, h, j] (total 340),  diff = 5
[a, b, d, e, h] (total 345)  vs  [c, f, g, i, j] (total 340),  diff = 5
[a, e, g, h, i] (total 340)  vs  [b, c, d, f, j] (total 345),  diff = 5
[a, c, d, g, h] (total 345)  vs  [b, e, f, i, j] (total 340),  diff = 5
```

It would be trivial to update to randomly choose the order of the two teams so that `a` is not always in the first team.

Comment: This is impressive, out of 14 players I added, it selected 5 sets of perfectly equal teams. The only thing I noticed though, is that there's  little variation in the players, 3/5 of the sets teams started with: `a, b, d, e, f` and the other 2/5 started with `a, b, c, d`. This is probably ok if there's no human input / choice involved, but more variety might be desirable, in which case you may need to sacrifice precision.

Comment: It's actually insane; using the 14 players from my answer, it can get up to 64 pairs of teams, each with an identical score of 475. If you can tack on a function to pick the 5 most varying sets, you've got a winner.

Comment: @Richard: I'm on my mobile now and can't code, but one simple possibility would be to do a random shuffle before the sort call.  It would not yield the most varying set (I'm not sure I even know how to quantify that) but would likely yield more varying possibilities when they are available.

Comment: @Richard: Added an update with the shuffle to help randomize.  This does not try to maximize entropy, simply to add some randomization between equal choices.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott this really helps me in a major way. Your solution is really nice and thanks again for such a detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

First, for your example you have, there are only 252 (10 choose 5) possible results. So trying all of them (brute force) is easily done.

In a more general matter, you can run a recursion method where at each level you assign a person to a team and check what can be done for the assigning of the next person. Keep in a global variable the best (closest) value you get to `sumOfAllSkillIndex/2` and who was in what team.

Comment: Agreed currently the order is changed within the team itself that is unneeded, could you help me with proposing the brute force code ?

Comment: @MarcoMancarne - well, actually, running the recursion IS brute force. You'll be checking all possible combinations...

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve the problem will post my solution

Answer (score 1):

You could take all combinationbs for only the half, because the rest of the unuused indices are the rest of the other selection.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  indices
0 1   3 4     7      one half selected
    2     5 6   8 9  other half is the rest without the first selected
```

This approach takes an index , sum and selected indices as well as a wanted target and a bias to select only result who have sums with a small bias of the target sum.

It feature as well a short circuit if the length of the selection is longer or the sum is greater than wanted target.

If the result is not wanted with sum or without indices, it could be adapted to the wanted result. Actually iit is easier to show only sum and indices.

```js
const
    getCombinations = (data, key, size, target, bias = Number.MAX_VALUE) => {
        const
            iter = (index = 0, sum = 0, right = []) => {
                if (right.length === size) {
                    if (Math.abs(target - sum) <= bias) result.push([sum, ...right]);
                    return;
                }
                if (index === data.length || sum > target + bias) return;

                iter(index + 1, sum + data[index][key], [...right, index]);
                iter(index + 1, sum, right);
            },
            result = [];

        iter();
        return result;
    },
    presentPlayers = [{ name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 }, { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 }, { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 }, { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }, { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 }, { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 }, { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 }, { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 }, { name: 'i', skillIndex: 50 }, { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 }],
    target = presentPlayers.reduce((s, { skillIndex }) => s + skillIndex, 0) / 2,
    result = getCombinations(
        presentPlayers,
        'skillIndex',
        presentPlayers.length >> 1,
        target,
        5
    );

console.log('sum', '|', 'indices');
result.forEach(([sum, ...indices]) => console.log(sum, '|', indices.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the absolute most balanced, but it'll be damn close every time, and very fast.

```js
const presentPlayers = [
    { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
    { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
    { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
    { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 },
    { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
    { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
    { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
    { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
    { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
    { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
    { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
    { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
    { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
    { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 },
];


function FastAssignment(players) {

    const sorted = players.sort((a, b) => b.skillIndex - a.skillIndex);

    // init with first two highest skilled players
    let team_a = [sorted.shift()];
    let team_b = [sorted.shift()];

    // start tracking total skill for each team
    let score_a = team_a[0].skillIndex;
    let score_b = team_b[0].skillIndex;

    // check them 2 at a time
    // assumes array is always divisible by two
    while (sorted.length > 0) {
        let a = sorted.shift()
        let b = sorted.shift()

        let high, low;

        // figure out which is higher / lower
        if (a.skillIndex >= b.skillIndex) {
            high = a;
            low = b;
        } else {
            high = b;
            low = a;
        }

        // check total score for team
        // assign lower skilled player to higher scored team
        if (score_a >= score_b) {
            team_a.push(low)
            team_b.push(high)
            score_a += low.skillIndex
            score_b += high.skillIndex
        } else {
            team_a.push(high)
            team_b.push(low)
            score_a += high.skillIndex
            score_b += low.skillIndex
        }
    }

    return [team_a, team_b]
}

function PrintTeamPair(pair){
    const [team_a, team_b] = pair;
    console.log(team_a)
    console.log('A total:', team_a.reduce((a, i) => a + i.skillIndex, 0))
    console.log(team_b)
    console.log('B total:', team_b.reduce((a, i) => a + i.skillIndex, 0))
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
}

function ShuffleTeamPair(pair){
    const [team_a, team_b] = pair;
    let selections = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < team_a.length; i++) {
        let a = [...team_a.slice(0, i), team_b[i], ...team_a.slice(i+1)];
        let b = [...team_b.slice(0, i), team_a[i], ...team_b.slice(i+1)];
        selections.push([a, b])
    }
    return selections;
}

const two_teams = FastAssignment(presentPlayers)
const shuffled = ShuffleTeamPair(two_teams)

PrintTeamPair(two_teams)

for(let pair of shuffled){
    PrintTeamPair(pair)
}
```

#### Output:

```
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 470
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 480
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 470
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 480
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 480
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 470
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 465
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 485
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 460
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 490
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 470
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 480
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
A total: 475
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
B total: 475
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[
  { name: 'a', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'c', skillIndex: 90 },
  { name: 'f', skillIndex: 80 },
  { name: 'g', skillIndex: 70 },
  { name: 'l', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'i', skillIndex: 45 },
  { name: 'n', skillIndex: 35 }
]
A total: 480
[
  { name: 'b', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'k', skillIndex: 100 },
  { name: 'm', skillIndex: 75 },
  { name: 'e', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'h', skillIndex: 60 },
  { name: 'j', skillIndex: 50 },
  { name: 'd', skillIndex: 25 }
]
B total: 470
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks !! However this will not give me multiple chocies and combinations right ? So for the same players the teams will always be the same

Comment: This gives a pretty good result, and fast. But the issue with greedy algorithms is that their not reliable and can be thrown off with some edge cases..

Comment: @MarcoMancarne I really need to read questions more carefully! I totally missed the multiple variations part. I've added a simple function to swap each player at the same index, so it'll give you as many variations as there are players-per-team.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov the more I think about this algorithm, the more impressed I am with it. I don't see any issue other than player numbers having to be even, and this can easily be handled. If you can describe a bad edge case, I'd love to hear it.