# Anyone know how I could change my code to ensure that I am able to render different variations of the users input

Tags: javascript, function, permutation, shuffle

Here is my code at the moment

```
solution () {
  let input = document.getElementById("number").value;
  if (input.length > 0) {
    const numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    let newInput = input.match(numbers).join("");
    let shuffled = newInput
    
    console.log(typeof newInput)
    alert(shuffled)  
  } else {
      console.log("Error please try again"); 
  }
}
```

Currently, as the user enters their input the code returns the numbers within their input.

I did look into permutation but I still new to coding and struggling to fix my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927452/recursively-print-all-permutations-of-a-string-javascript